# Web browser offline application cache with video files?

Tags: html, video, mp4, browser-cache

I am trying to make a site available offline in a web browser (specifically: Mobile Safari and/or Google Chrome), using a manifest file to load the offline content into the application cache.

This works just fine for images, html content and even font files. But not so for the videos I am trying to store. Mobile Safari is asking to increase storage to 50MB (just as it should) to accomodate the videos, but when going offline the videos are not displayed. All in all the cached content amounts to 37MB.

I am using JWPlayer to show the videos (setting the HTML5 player version as the preferred player), but I have also tried the HTML5 video tag on its own to no avail. The JWPlayer is returning the "Could not load video file" message, just as if the URL was invalid, when going offline (but they work fine online). The videos are H264 encoded in MP4 containers.

Is Mobile Safari on iPad at all capable of storing and retrieving MP4 (or other video) files? Is there any special trick that needs to be employed?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Safari itself doesn't play the videos. They're played by the QuickTime plugin, which ignores the browser's caches. See [this article](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-html5-application-cache-mobile-web-apps).

I don't know of any workaround (other than PhoneGap etc.), but I would certainly love to have one!

Answer (score 0):

You could not use the JWplayer in offline (at least with your current version). In their script (swf), it is fetching some external script from their server (include their logo) such as

[http://p.jwpcdn.com/ ... /jwpsrv_frq.js](http://p.jwpcdn.com/%20...%20/jwpsrv_frq.js)

[http://p.jwpcdn.com/...../jwpsrv.js](http://p.jwpcdn.com/6/5/jwpsrv.js)

[http://p.jwpcdn.com/...../logo.png](http://p.jwpcdn.com/...%20/5/logo.png) (JwPlayer text)

I think it's all about their authorization and license checking. It would take you an amount to get away that logo for the paid version, they may ask your domain and they will add it into their list of the customer's valid website domain, and they also give you a script in the static link and you can add it into your cache file.